# Return IQueryable<T> as IEnumerable<T> will cause in database call?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ienumerable, iqueryable

I use Entity Framework. Let's say I have a method:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers() // return IEnumerable<User>
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        return context.Users;
    }
}
```

---

Now when I call:

```
var users = GetUsers();
```

Will this operation perform a database query or not?

Comment: no, because `IQueryable<T> : IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @DLeh yeah, I've checked this but I was a little confused.

Comment: Maybe the confusion was from OP reading something about how `AsEnumerable()` can trigger the query (since it enumerates the collection)?

Comment: @moarboilerplate [AsEnumerable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't do anything. It simple do a cast. Alone it doesn't cause enumeration or anything. `The AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>) method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<T> itself.`

Comment: @xanatos do you mean AsEnumerable doesn't trigger a database query?

Comment: @andrei alone no, simply causes the next Linq method chained to be executed locally

Comment: @xanatos thanks! I was mistakenly thinking that it calls database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you don't do anything with it, no.

However, if you try to iterate over the results (or call `Count()` etc) then it will try to make a database call... and I'd expect it to then fail, because you've disposed of the context at that point.

Comment: @Jon what if I have list on view? should I send IEnumerable or List which again iterates latter?

Comment: @brykneval: Not sure what you mean by "list on view", or what your second question means. You should probably ask a question in a new post.

Comment: @JonSkeet can I send IEnumerable<T> only to view which will iterate on Html View rather than sending ToList() which might iterate once on .ToList() and other on foreach loop in html view?

Comment: @brykneval: That's still not clear, and it should still be in a new post.

Comment: @JonSkeet sad but I am banned for low post, reason stackoverflow is more blog to me so I ask and answer with less homework and get banned :-(

Comment: @brykneval: I suggest you work hard to improve your existing questions then, so the ban will be lifted. See the message you got when you received the ban.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did but none review it back, coz its not that popular or I am not still clear myself most of times